# Selenium Sessions Timing Out When Running Tests in Docker Containers

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

I'm facing an issue when attempting to run Selenium tests from a Jenkins container against a Selenium container. In the Selenium container logs, I observe messages like "Session created by the Node" followed after 5 minutes by "Session id [some_id] timed out, stopping...", "Deleted session from local Session Map", and "Releasing slot for session id [some_id]".

In Jenkins, tests have de following missage error:  "org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
Build info: version: '4.16.1', revision: '9b4c83354e'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.14.21-150400.24.81-default', java.version: '17.0.10"

The same tests executed against a local Selenium instance work fine.

Here are the details of my setup:

Both the Jenkins and Selenium containers are on the same Docker network.
I've verified the connectivity between the Jenkins and Selenium containers, and the necessary ports (default: 4444) are open.

Tests have appropriate waits and timeouts.

Are there any specific configurations or common issues that could lead to session timeouts in a Dockerized Selenium environment? Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.